# Setting SATA HDD spindown time for Western Digital Green drives

Tags: hard-drive, spindown

I am able to spindown my SATA HDDs by using

```
sudo hdparm -y /dev/sdc
```

The state shown by

```
sudo hdparm -C /dev/sdc
```

changes from active/idle to standby (and I can hear the HDD spin down).

However, using

```
sudo hdparm -S5 /dev/sdc
```

doesn't spin down the drive after 5*5 = 25secs.

Some additional information:

- AHCI is enabled.
- I am using Western Digital Green drives.
- APM_level = not supported
- Filesystem is ext4

Edit: This question is not a duplicate to [How can I control HDD spin down time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39760/how-can-i-control-hdd-spin-down-time) because it addresses Western Digital Green drives, which will not work with hdparm.

Comment: You may need to set Advanced Power Management to something lower then 128 first, as high values (128-254) do not allow spin-down. Try `sudo hdparm -B 127 /dev/sdc`.

Comment: hdparm -B doesn't work, because APM_level = not supported on the HDDs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After more research, it seems that the -B and -S options of hdparm just doesn't work with certain Western Digital (and maybe other) drives.

This includes my WD10EADS, WD10EACS and WD20EARX.

I found a solution: [hd-idle](http://hd-idle.sourceforge.net/)

To install `hd-idle` on Ubuntu:

```
wget https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/hd-idle/hd-idle-1.04.tgz
tar xvfz hd-idle*.tgz
cd hd-idle
sudo apt-get install debhelper
sudo dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -rfakeroot
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i hd-idle_*.deb
# To run at startup:
sudo update-rc.d hd-idle defaults
nano /etc/default/hd-idle
```

`/etc/default/hd-idle` content:

```
START_HD_IDLE=true
# Optional, to limit to a specific drives:
# (leading '-i 0' to disable hd-idle on other disks)
HD_IDLE_OPTS="-i 0 -a /dev/disk/by-uuid/DRIVE1UID -i 600 -a /dev/disk/by-uuid/DRIVE2UID -i 600"
```

Disable system-managed disk power management settings in `Storage` > `Physical Disks` > `Disk properties` (redundant).

```
sudo service hd-idle start
```

Check:

```
sudo hdparm -C /dev/sd[a-z]
```

Comment: WD30EZRS and WD30EZRX are also affected.

Comment: Thanks: this might explain why I can only stop my daft WD from constantly going on/off standby - and thus accruing load cycles dangerously quickly towards the mfg threshold of 300000 - by disabling both APM and WDidle. Neither is effective alone. I disabled -Standby for good measure, though I'm not sure it matters once the others are off. The HD claims to support APM, but settings > 128 don't disable standby as claimed, so it exhibits the cycling problem. This is a "Blue" model as follows: "Model Family:     Western Digital Scorpio Blue Serial ATA (AF)
Device Model:     WDC WD3200BPVT-22JJ5T0"

Comment: on debian buster i had to `apt install apparmor-utils` as well. use `sudo aa-disable /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.man` before and `sudo aa-enforce /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.man` after invoking `dpkg-buildpackage`

Comment: afaik this helps with all scorpio (e.g. WD 2.5" end user) hdds

Answer (score 0):

The ubuntu way seems to be the *laptop mode**

How to:

```
apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

Afterwards you are able to configure individual power/standby settings through

```
vim /etc/hdparm.conf
```

And check your current *laptop mode* state with:

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode
```

If you want to know more:

- [wiki.archlinux.org/.../Laptop_Mode_Tools](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Laptop_Mode_Tools#Installation)
- [Ubuntu and agressive powermanagement](http://ubuntudemon.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/ubuntu-is-not-causing-aggressive-power-management/)
- There's a note at the end of: vim /etc/default/acpi-support

Comment: This won't work for Western Digital Green drives.