# How to load HDD lazily?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have a laptop with an SSD and an HDD. I tend to use the SSD only. On Windows 8 when I don't use the HDD for a few minutes, it goes idle and the laptop is completely silent, because SSD makes no noise. However, on Ubuntu the laptop is constantly making noise, which suggests that the HDD is active even though I do not use it. Is there a way to make Ubuntu lazily load the HDD? I like it when my laptop is silent and energy efficient .

Comment: Maybe http://info4admins.com/tips-to-spindown-your-hard-disk-in-debian-or-ubuntu/ can help you

Comment: @R110 thanks, I also found this relevant question http://askubuntu.com/questions/39760/how-can-i-control-hdd-spin-down-time