# How to tune disk parameters in hdparm.conf by UUID?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a disk that was spinning down too fast and

```
/dev/sda {
    apm_battery = 254
}
```

per [How can I control HDD spin down time?](https://askubuntu.com/q/39760/20275) helped. The problem is that I plan on switching the disk in future. How can I make sure that apm_battery will affect only that specific disk?

Comment: Why don't you use the procedure given in the post you linked to? That's using a UUID.

Comment: I don't know how did I miss it. Maybe because I was looking for APM  settings only.