# HDD standby mode does not turn on automatically

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, power-management, low-power

I have added the following lines

```
/dev/hda {
   spindown_time = 60
}

/dev/hdb {
   spindown_time = 60
}

/dev/hdc {
   spindown_time = 60
}
```

to the end of my `/etc/hdparm.conf` file and rebooted.

Unfortunately, no any effect of these lines observed. For example, `/dev/hdb` which I rarely use shows

```
$ sudo smartctl -i -n standby /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-37-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD40EFRX-68WT0N0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC4EFSNCNX5
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 26020b658
Firmware Version: 82.00A82
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Oct 22 05:31:21 2014 MSK
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
Power mode is:    ACTIVE or IDLE
```

How to check/force power conserving works?

**UDPATE**

I have tried all things, including ones in so called "duplicate" question, but they didn't work.

I can put drive into standby mode manually with

```
hdparm -y /dev/sdb
```

and it will stay in this mode until used. But once it used, it will never go into standby itself.

Is it possible to look standby timer, i.e. timer, which is counting time after last activity? Without this timer, auto standby feature can't work. And if this timer exists, but unavailable, then atuo standby can't be debugged.

Comment: So you tried [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/224936/44179) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/387876/44179)?

Comment: How to check explicitly? Is there any way to see how standby timer counts?

Comment: I'm unaware of any method right now.. If it's a desktop you can sometimes hear it spin up from standby. A could test would be to open a Nautilus window, wait, and then suddenly open a folder.