# How can I turn a secondary HDD on and off using a bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, hard-drive, power-management

For power saving reasons I want to turn off a second hard drive.
When the secondary HDD is needed I want to turn it on.

I found a [way to turn off](https://askubuntu.com/a/671889) but I need to be able to turn off and turn on.

How can I turn a secondary HDD on and off from a bash script?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Doesn't it automatically turn on when accessed?

Comment: It would go to suspend state after a specific time when you don't use it and will be up and running immediately after accessing it.

Comment: Related: [How can I control HDD spin down time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39760/how-can-i-control-hdd-spin-down-time)