# Eject second internal hard drive in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-gnome

I have SSD and HDD hard drives in my laptop and I have `Ubuntu` on SSD and `windows 10` in HDD and (sometimes) I want to eject HDD when I am working on Ubuntu (because of power saving and...), how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In the Files app, you have a sidebar on the left. You will see a little triangle next to the mounted device.

[image]

Click on it, and your drive will be unmounted (a.k.a. "ejected").

If you have chosen to see mounted drives on the desktop, you will have a right-click option "Eject" there as well.

Comment: I want to power off my hard drive, by unmounting or ejecting partitions the hard drive is still working (I can sense it's sound of working), how I can eject it completely?

Comment: That is strictly not "ejecting". See https://askubuntu.com/questions/671683/how-to-turn-off-hard-drive-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me:

`sudo hdparm -Y /dev/sdX`