# How to power off Samsung SSD drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid

I have Samsung SSD 860 EVO 500GB drive with Windows 10 and two HDD in RAID1. I started using Linux on different drive and I would like to power off my drives connected to windows. I am using `sudo udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdX` command and I am able to power off the HDD drives but I see in statistics that my SDD is still working (Just see amount of hours which it is working)

Moreover why even if I power off the HDD drives I still see them in `sudo udisksctl status`. Is it possible to see in status that they are powered off?

Third strange thing, during using `sudo udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdX` I got information there there is no usb device connected but still my HDD is powered off.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off hard drive in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671683/how-to-turn-off-hard-drive-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Unfortunately no. Still I see that hours counter of SSD is increasing. It is strange. It seems that there is no command to really power off the SSD drive.

Comment: When you look at the [SSD life %](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038701/how-do-i-check-system-health/1038711#1038711) you see it lasts for 300 years so I wouldn't really worry about it.

Comment: Ok, maybe I care to much ;) Thanks.