# Ubuntu with Xfce becomes temporarily unresponsive for one or two mins

Tags: 16.04, xfce

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Xfce on an Intel Core 2 Duo 2.53GHz and 4Gb RAM, which I've had for a while and which isn't keeping up with the increasing demands of software updates to Firefox and Xfce etc.

If I leave the computer unused (but on) for any length of time (typically overnight but often shorter) the GUI becomes unresponsive for a couple of minutes but then comes back to life.

I really only use these apps: Firefox, Handbrake, backuppc, terminal.

Since it also covers various other non-GUI functions like backuppc, iptables, bind, dhcp, there may be a lot of unnecessary server-side stuff going on.

This is my freemem output:

```
adam@gondor:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3883         683         909         144        2290        2771
Swap:          4024         186        3837
adam@gondor:~$
```

Can I diagnose and fix this without adding more hardware, and apart from not using Firefox anymore?

Comment: There no Ubuntu version 16.  Which Ubuntu version do you really have? 16.04 or 16.10?  They are significantly different.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: So it is becoming unresponsive if you leave it alone for a while ? Your first step could be to make sure your [HDD is not spinning down](https://askubuntu.com/a/891178/783023) .

Comment: That's right - normally it's fine but overnight something seems to nacker it. The disk drive setting in my Disks utility is set to `OFF`. It seems that functionality might not work for the brand of hard drive - Western Digital to be specific and mine is a Hitachi, although I turned it `ON` and watched the syslog, which showed `udisksd` doing its stuff without errors or warnings. I have left `Stand-by`=`OFF`, but set `APM` to `perform better 255 (disabled)`. `1` is `spin down permitted`. It was just `OFF`

Comment: Maybe try using [`iotop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/iotop) to see what thread is using disk I/O? I frequently need to ionice things like `tracker-store`, and `iotop` lets you do this interactively.

Comment: OK I see stuff running like backuppc but this is a dual core CPU - how come the other core isn't free to run firefox?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by GUI "unresponsive". Does that mean the mouse pointer won't move or applications won't refresh? Leave the terminal running `top` overnight. When you come back in the morning is it still updating every few seconds? Press the `Q` key to exit `top`. Can you immediately type some terminal command such as `ll` or does it pause for a couple of minutes?

Comment: GUI "unresponsiveness" == the mouse moves, but the effect of the clicks is massively delayed. The command line is not so badly affected - I can run top and quit out of it, although it is slightly slowed down. That's probably got access to the other CPU core right, but the GUI thread/s ... glacial

Comment: have you checked the cpu governor ?  Maybe its in powersafe mode or something ?