# HDD aggressively spinning down

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive, spindown

I have 2 Iron Wolf drives that are aggressively spinning down.
I have tried turning on the standby feature in "drive settings".
I have also run `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdc | grep level` and get no output.
So I run `sudo hdparm -S 120 /dev/sdc` and get

```
/dev/sdc:
 setting standby to 120 (10 minutes)
```

But nothing. I still see the drive in the "disks" utility with "zzz" immediately after copying a file over to the drive.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Chris

EDIT: running 18.04

Comment: you need to specify the version and type of ubuntu you're using. add the tag at least.

Comment: are you sure it has spun down? Could you recheck with `smartctl -i -n standby /dev/sdX` if *Power mode is: Active, Idle, or Standby* - `smartctl` is part of package `smartmontools`

Comment: Hi. Here is the output ```sudo smartctl -i -n standby /dev/sdc
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.18.0-22-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Device is in STANDBY mode, exit(2)``` SMART also reports high read error rates on both drives. Perhaps worth mentioning is that they are connected to sata 2.0 ports.

Answer (score 1):

Your hdparm command doesn't work because you probably also have the `udisks2` daemon running which spins down the disk on its own schedule (and/or overwrites your settings).

Thus, you can either stop/disable/mask that daemon, e.g. to just temporarily stop it:

```
systemctl stop udisks2.service
```

Or change the [`StandbyTimeout=` udisk2 setting](http://manpath.be/f33/8/udisks#L45) for your disk.