# Mounted drive needs to be double-clicked at least once before other applications can use it

Tags: dual-boot, mount, automount, drive

I have mounted an NTFS drive from my Windows install. I believe it "automounts" as it is visible in "Other Locations" > "On This Computer" every time at startup.

However, any bookmarks or references to folders within this drive (located at "/media/gvcallen/Data") do not work until I have double clicked on the Data drive at least once. By "references", I mean applications which have "recent files" within that drive, or simply trying to open I file within that drive from somewhere else.

The error message I get is usually something along the lines of "Could not find file xxx" or "Unable to open file xxx".

Have I not automounted the drive properly? How can I solve this?

Comment: The lists you mention like recent files  do not update real time and are simply stored somewhere. The most likely cause of the @problem@ is the drive has spun down and you are waking it up. So it needs a few seconds to wake and then it finds the file. Not sure you need to double click to wake it but something needs to.

Comment: what @david posted is possible so ...what does `sudo hdparm -I /dev/{device} | grep level`  show for your mount. Get the  device from `df -H`. edit: darn my memory is good, Knew I posted it somewhere https://askubuntu.com/questions/39760/how-can-i-control-hdd-spin-down-time :D

Comment: Addition: spin down for USB might also be a BIOS option on your machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is normal behavior for partitions on internal drives. Internal partitions by default are not automatically mounted if they are not automounted through the configuration file `/etc/fstab`. Such partitions are shown in the left panel of Files, and you can click these icons to mount the partition before use.

If you did not take special action, then indeed you do not have automounted that partition. You can automount by manually editing the configuration file `/etc/fstab`, although you can also use the utility "Disks" (installed in a default Ubuntu system) to configure the drive for automount during startup.

In Disks, click the partition. Then click the "gear" icon and select "Edit mount options". In the "Mount Options" dialog, select "Mount at system startup" to have the partition automount.

*On a related side note*: make sure Windows Fast Startup is disabled, and that the Windows system is fully shutdown before you use the partition in Ubuntu. Otherwise, the partition may not be properly closed, and that will give problems mounting and using it in Ubuntu.

Comment: I presume the issue is the windows fast startup. thanks for the help!